# msp430G2553 launchpad programming

Tags: msp430

I am making my program using msp430g2553 launch pad. In this i have taken input from P2.4 and i want my output from P2.0, P2.1 and P2.2.

In this program i have to generate the pulse of 500ms from input. and my output will be three low pulses from the three pins. Meaning  whenever i connect my oscilloscope probe to 2.4 i can see the pulse. But the program i made it didn't work. when i connect to the oscilloscope it is showing nothing.

when my input pulse is high i will get the three low pulses output.

here is my code, please check it and tell me what is wrong in the code? since it doesn't contains any error.

code:

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
#define CPU_F ((double)16000000)
#define delay_us(x) __delay_cycles((long)(CPU_F*(double)x/1000000.0))
#define delay_ms(x) __delay_cycles((long)(CPU_F*(double)x/1000.0))

char C_1, C_2;
void System_Clock_Init( void )
{
char i;
_NOP();
WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Close Watching dog
delay_ms(50);                  
if( ( CALBC1_16MHZ == 0xff ) || ( CALDCO_16MHZ == 0xff ) )              
 ((void (*)())RESET_VECTOR)();
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_16MHZ;                                                                
DCOCTL = CALDCO_16MHZ;  //MCLK=DCOCLK=16MHz
BCSCTL2 = 0x06;//SMCLK=DCOCLK/8=2MHz
BCSCTL3 = 0x00;                                                                                            
IE1 &= ~OFIE;                                                                                                  

   do
   {
    IFG1 &= ~OFIFG;     
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        _NOP();
    }
    }
     while (IFG1 & OFIFG);   

      _NOP();
   }

  void IO_INIT(void)
   {
   NOP();
   P2SEL &= ~BIT4;
   P2SEL2 &= ~BIT4;
   P2REN &= ~BIT4;
  /*P2DIR |= BIT2;*/
   P2IES |= BIT4;
   P2IE  |= BIT4;
   P2IFG  &= ~BIT4;

   P2SEL &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);
   P2SEL2 &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);
   P2REN &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);
  //P2DIR &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);
   P2OUT &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);

   P2SEL &= ~BIT2;
   P2SEL2 &= ~BIT2;
   P2REN &= ~BIT2;
   //P3DIR &= ~BIT1;
   P2OUT &= ~BIT2;


    }

    void main(void)
     {
     System_Clock_Init();
    _NOP();
    //WDTCTL = WDT_ARST_1000;
    _NOP();      
     IO_INIT();
    _NOP();
    _EINT();//open all interrupt
    _NOP();
     LPM3;
     _NOP();
    while(1);
     }


     #pragma vector = PORT2_VECTOR
     __interrupt void PORT_C_Interrupt(void)

     {

     _NOP();
      delay_us(20);

      if( C_1 == 0xff)
      {
      if(!( P2IN & BIT4 )) C_2 = 0xff;
      }
      else
      {
      if(!( P2IN & BIT4 )) C_1 = 0xff;
      }
      if(( C_1 == 0xff) && ( C_2 == 0xff))
      {
      //output A B D
       P2OUT |= BIT0;
       delay_ms(2);
       P2OUT |= BIT1;
       P2OUT &= ~BIT0;
       delay_ms(2);
       P2OUT |= BIT2;
       P2OUT &= ~BIT1;
       delay_ms(2);
       P2OUT &= ~BIT2;   
       delay_ms(2);

       P2OUT ^= BIT1;                 
       P2IFG &= ~BIT1;                
       C_1 =0x00;
       C_2 =0x00;
       }
       _NOP();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
P2IFG &= ~BIT1;
```

The interrupt came from P2.4. This line does not clear the interrupt for pin 4, so the interrupt handler will be called continuously.

```c
/*P2DIR |= BIT2;*/
//P2DIR &= ~(BIT0+BIT1);
```

If you actually want those pins to te outputs, it would be a good idea not to comment out their configuration.

Comment: If i didn't comment out those pins, i am getting output as one pulse from only one pin i.e. P2.2, but I want output from all the pins.